# How to change multiple sites dns in CloudFlare account?

Tags: automation, dns, command-line-interface, terraform, cloudflare

I have a lot of sites on an CloudFlare account, sometimes when servers are migrate, i need to change every domain DNS in CF manually. How can I use some tool or script, that helps me to download all domains info, and than easy change it?
Maybe some Terraform example? I didnt use Terraform yet, so just thinking about ways how to automate this proccess.
Tnx.

Comment: Can you give an example of the changes you find yourself making? And how many sites are on your CloudFlare account? Would you be open to writing the Terraform code for every CloudFlare DNS record using the https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/cloudflare/r/record.html resource and importing all your records into Terraform's state file?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, its more than 100 domains per account.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, i need to change DNS A record. Just change IP of server in all domains per CF account.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, yes, if it the best way, ill write Terraform file. But, can i somehow optimize that process and download all domain list in Terraform format for that task, or i need manually copypaste every domain in Terraform template? If so...ok, but if more fast wey are exist, i will be glad.

Comment: It's multiple domains all pointing to the same IP address?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, yes

Comment: quick Terrafrom demo https://stackoverflow.com/a/70897825/82686

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) for this. There are an official Cloudflare Provider, the documentation for which you can find [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cloudflare/cloudflare/latest/docs).

When using the provider "directly", your Terraform configuration will look like this:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    cloudflare = {
      source  = "cloudflare/cloudflare"
      version = ">= 3.12.1"
    }
  }
}

variable "cloudflare_api_token" {
  type      = string
  sensitive = true
}

provider "cloudflare" {
  api_token = var.cloudflare_api_token
}

resource "cloudflare_zone" "acme_com" {
  zone = "acme.com"
}
```

You may be interested in the following Cloudflare resources to use them in your configuration:

- [cloudflare_zone](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cloudflare/cloudflare/latest/docs/resources/zone)
- [cloudflare_zone_settings_override](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cloudflare/cloudflare/latest/docs/resources/zone_settings_override)
- [cloudflare_record](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cloudflare/cloudflare/latest/docs/resources/record)

Also, you can use this [module](https://github.com/alex-feel/terraform-cloudflare-zone). Then your configuration may look like this:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    cloudflare = {
      source  = "cloudflare/cloudflare"
      version = ">= 3.12.1"
    }
  }
}

variable "cloudflare_api_token" {
  type      = string
  sensitive = true
}

provider "cloudflare" {
  api_token = var.cloudflare_api_token
}

module "acme_com" {
  source = "registry.terraform.io/alex-feel/zone/cloudflare"
  version = "1.7.0"
  zone = "acme.com"
}
```

There are [examples](https://github.com/alex-feel/terraform-cloudflare-zone/tree/main/examples) to help you get started with the module.

And here is a concrete, ready-to-use example that you can use in your specific case when using the module:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    cloudflare = {
      source  = "cloudflare/cloudflare"
      version = ">= 3.12.1"
    }
  }
}

variable "cloudflare_api_token" {
  type      = string
  sensitive = true
}

provider "cloudflare" {
  api_token = var.cloudflare_api_token
}

locals {
  # All your zones go here
  zones = ["acme.com", "example.com"]
  # Your IP for A records for all the zones goes here
  ip = "192.0.2.1"
}

module "all_domains" {
  source  = "registry.terraform.io/alex-feel/zone/cloudflare"
  version = "1.7.0"

  for_each = toset(local.zones)

  zone = each.value

  records = [
    {
      record_name = "a_main"
      type        = "A"
      value       = local.ip
    }
  ]
}
```

In this case, it will be enough for you to list all your domains in the `zones` variable and specify the desired IP in the `ip` variable. As a result, an A record with the specified IP will be created for each of your domains.

To get all your zones you can use Cloudflare API [List Zones](https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-list-zones) method. So your request will look like this:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN'
```

Comment: Cool, this is exactly what i want. Tnx!