# Can I version control CloudFlare configuration?

Tags: cloudflare

I am utilizing Cloudflare for a public website. Recently, I have been adjusting many different configuration values via the website/UI. Is there a way to download/upload the configuration so that it can be version-controlled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure Cloudflare using Terraform. Check out Terraform Cloudflare Provider [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cloudflare/cloudflare/latest/docs).

You can use a tool called [cf-terraforming](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cf-terraform/) delivered by Cloudflare that allows to download the Cloudflare setup into Terraform.

Comment: That's super helpful! That makes deployment much easier, I'm curious - is there a way to download the current state of a site to use as the starting point?

Comment: You can use cf-terraforming. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick demo of what it would look like using Terraform:

```tf
locals {
  domain   = "example.com"
  hostname = "example.com" # TODO: Varies by environment
}

variable "CLOUDFLARE_ACCOUNT_ID" {}
variable "CLOUDFLARE_API_TOKEN" { sensitive = true }

provider "cloudflare" {
  account_id = var.CLOUDFLARE_ACCOUNT_ID
  api_token  = var.CLOUDFLARE_API_TOKEN
}

resource "cloudflare_zone" "default" {
  zone = local.domain
  plan = "free"
}

resource "cloudflare_record" "a" {
  zone_id = cloudflare_zone.default.id
  name    = local.hostname
  value   = "192.0.2.1"
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = 1
  proxied = true
}
```

Find a complete example, see [Terraform Starter Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/terraform-starter-kit):

- `infra/dns-zone.tf`
- `infra/dns-records.tf`

It works especially great with Terraform Cloud "backend" which provides a free account.